# Ошибка при запуске llama-2, что я делаю не так?

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda

Пытаюсь запустить на Ubuntu в Anaconda в Spyder языковую модель llama-2-7b/.
Но сразу получаю ошибку:

/home/ubu/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/**init**.py:614: UserWarning: torch.set_default_tensor_type() is deprecated as of PyTorch 2.1, please use torch.set_default_dtype() and torch.set_default_device() as alternatives. (Triggered internally at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytotch_1699449183005/work/torch/csrc/tensor/python_tensor.cpp:451.) _ C._set_default_tensor_type(t)

После идет рестарт ядра, без моего участия.
"Функция torch.set_default_tensor_type() устарела". Кажется, что то надо обновить, но я не понимаю, что. Ведь все компоненты только только установил. Может кто подскажет.